# How to add a global decorator in Storybook

Tags: storybook

In ReactJs project you can use [.storybook/preview.js](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/overview#configure-story-rendering) file to add global decorators and parameters. How to achieve this same behaviour with `@storybook/react-native`?

What I need is to wrap all my stories with `ThemeProvider` but the unique way that I found is to wrap individual stories with `.addDecorator()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit **storybook/index.js**, by using `addDecorator` on it.

Example:

```
import React from 'react'
import { getStorybookUI, configure, addDecorator } from '@storybook/react-native'
import Decorator from './Decorator'


addDecorator(storyFn => (
  <Decorator>
    {storyFn()}
  </Decorator>
))

// import stories
configure(() => {
  require('../stories')
}, module)


const StorybookUI = getStorybookUI({ onDeviceUI: true })
export default StorybookUI;;
```

Comment: hey, could you update the answer? Since this is not valid in version 6.5 anymore. Thanks

Comment: from `@storybook/react-native` README:
"NOTE: @storybook/react-native and @storybook/react-native-server are now on a different release cycle from the Storybook Core packages (@storybook/react, @storybook/vue, etc.). The last stable version of @storybook/react-native is 5.3.25 and it should be used with 5.3 versions of Storybook Core"

Answer (score 7):

Found an updated answer in Storybook's own [documentation](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/decorators#global-decorators).

```
// .storybook/preview.js

import React from 'react';

export const decorators = [
  (Story) => (
    <div style={{ margin: '3em' }}>
      <Story />
    </div>
  ),
];
```

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2021, using storybook v5.3.25, the above answer does not work. However I have managed to figure out a solution.

Decorators must be added to the **storybook/index.js** file in the following format:

```
import { ThemeDecorator } from './storybook/ThemeDecorator';

addDecorator(withKnobs); // inbuilt storybook addon decorator
addDecorator(ThemeDecorator);// custom decorator

configure(() => {
  loadStories();
}, module);
```

in this instance, **ThemeDecorator.js** is a simple wrapper component that renders your story, it would look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'theme-provider';

export const ThemeDecorator = (getStory) => (
  <Provider>{getStory()}</Provider>
);
```

Importantly, the addDecorator function expects a React component (not a wrapper function as other examples claim), that it will render, with its props being a reference to an individual story at runtime.